# How can i set rep_delay in ibm qiskit runtime

Tags: primitive, quantum-computing, qiskit

I want to be able to speed up the sampling done by qiskit_ibm_runtime.Estimator, by reducing the time qubits are allowed to decay to their ground state. I realise this might introduce errors in the intial state but it may help me to estimate the possible sampling speed if error rates were not my priority, or if error rate improved with QPU developments.
When not using qiskit runtime the rep_delay can be set when running a back end

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import RealAmplitudes
circuit = RealAmplitudes(num_qubits=2, reps=2)
backend.run(circuit, rep_delay=0.00001)
```

Can a this delay be set when using the primitive Estimator or Sampler? I tried

```
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Estimator, Session, QiskitRuntimeService
from qiskit.circuit.library import RealAmplitudes
circuit = RealAmplitudes(num_qubits=2, reps=2)
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_cloud", token=API_Key_my, instance=crn_pay)

backend={0:"ibm_algiers",1:"ibmq_qasm_simulator",2:"ibmq_manila"}[0]
    with Session(service=service, backend=backend):
        job = qiskit_ibm_runtime.Sampler(options={"shots": 2048} ).run(circuit, rep_delay=0.00001)
```

but it responded with error

```
got an unexpected keyword argument 'rep_delay'
```

Answer (score 1):

`rep_delay` is not a documented option, but sampler still accepts it if you pass it in the options using

```
Options(execution={"rep_delay": your_rep_delay_value})
```